# TFS Build -- Get parts of the source code using different labels

Tags: tfsbuild, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I'm migrating a homegrown build system to TFS Build and there are some unique challenges with getting the source code.  Originally the code was kept in VSS and to allow the various tiers of the code to be independent, each tier had its own label.  A text file had five labels that represented what was needed to make a final build and this file was under the "master label".  At build time the file was read each tier was retrieved from VSS using its specific label and the whole source code tree built.

How can I can get the source in different folders under individual labels and assemble the source code for a full build?

I've looked in the default template to see how the code is retrieved but it's not clear if I can use a different label for each Source Settings entry as the code is retrieved.

Another idea I had was to call sub templates from a master template but that really seemed like overkill.

In TFS Build, I see the general idea is to let the build apply a label to all the source code and then get under that label.  I also see that I can specify a label in the Build Process part of the default template.

Comment: This very much reminds me of the use of config specs in Clearcase.

Answer (score 0):

Team Build assumes that everything will be under *one* label. But that label can contain folders at different versions, so instead of your "Master text file" you could create a Master Label that contains all the files at different versions. **This is a very uncommon practice** but it should work:

```
tf label MasterLabel $/Project/FolderA /recursive /version:c1
tf label MasterLabel $/Project/FolderB /recursive /version:c50
tf label MasterLabel $/Project/FolderC /recursive /version:c100
```

As long as the path you're applying the label to, does not overlap, it should work.

To get the sources, use:

```
tf get /resursive /version:LMasterLabel
```

A better way to do it, would be to either package the application using NuGet packages and use a NuGet server for dependency management, or to indeed create multiple build definitions with an optional master definition that "grabs" all the outputs of the individual builds. That's basically what the Lab Management Template does as well.